# How can we describe the similarity between trees?

Tags: trees

For example, I have a program generates two ASTs, and I want to compare the two trees.

I've tried to treat the trees as graphs, but I think it doesn't show the particularity of trees.

Comment: Look into Tree Edit Distance algorithms. A common one is "[Zhang and Shasha: An Algorithm for Comparing Similarity Between Two Trees](https://arxiv.org/abs/1508.03381)".